# What is the etymology of "la magneto"?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico, género, préstamo-lingüístico

*La magneto* is rare among *-o* terminal words in that it is feminine (at least in some dialects). The [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ntf3P51) gives its ultimate etymology as:

> Del lat. *magnes, -ētis* 'imán<sup>1</sup>'.

Given the word has clearly not been directly inherited from Latin<sup>1 2</sup>, what is its etymology? Does it explain why it is feminine?

---

<sup>1. The only occurrence of *magneto* before 1881 in the RAE's CORDE is one example from the 14th century: "... turniano **magneto** leboreto..." (*Gran crónica de España*, Juan Fernández de Heredia (1385)).</sup>
<sup>2. The only pre-19th century occurrences of it in Google ngrams are references to [Ancient Magnetum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lousada) (*Magneto* in Portuguese).</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at its first modern use in Spanish, the [earliest appearances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22magneto%22&lr=lang_es&tbs=lr:sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X) of *magneto* in Spanish are as a compound adjective in the phrases *"máquina magneto-eléctrica"* and *"aparato magneto-eléctrico"*. It appears the former term was more common, and the abbreviated form *magneto* eventually superseded it in popularity.

This etymology is confirmed in the following dictionary:

> *magneto,* abrev. de *máquina magneto-eléctrica* [< lat. **magnēs, -ētis,** 'iman'], f.
>
> - [*Lexicón etimológico y semántico del Latín y de las voces actuales que proceden de raíces latinas o griegas*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I_gbBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA342&lpg=PA342&dq=magneto), Santiago Segura Munguía (p.342)

---

The similar word *dínamo* appears to be feminine for analogous reasons:

> *L'Electrical Review de Londres* propone dos medios de utilizar la fuerza del viento conmbinada con la del agua para obtener una fuerza regular y constante con aplicación á **las máquinas dínamo-eléctricas.**
>
> - [*Revista agustiniana dedicada al Santo Obispo de Hipona en su admirable conversión á la fe*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zsAKC9-PNUAC&q=%22d%C3%ADnamo%22), Volume 6 (1883)