# Which feminine words end "-o"?

Tags: sustantivos, género

What are the feminine exceptions to the general rule "Spanish nouns ending -o are masculine"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only a few, and they come under a handful of classifications:

- **From Catalan:**

  - nao<sub>(← nau ← nāvis)</sub>, seo <sub>(← seu ← sēdēs)</sub>
- **Latin irregular:**

  - [mano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32/por-qu%C3%A9-es-la-palabra-mano-femenina), ratio, libido
- **Female persons:**

  - [seño](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28709/formas-reducidas-de-se%C3%B1or-ra), virago, hijadalgo <sub>(hija de algo)</sub>
- **Abbreviations:**<sup>1</sup>

  - furgo <sub>(furgoneta)</sub>, moto <sub>(motocicleta)</sub>
  - demo <sub>(demostración)</sub>, radio <sub>(radiodifusión)</sub>
  - eco <sub>(ecografía)</sub>, foto <sub>(fotografía)</sub>, telefoto <sub>(telefotografía)</sub>
  - dínamo/dinamo <sub>([máquina dínamo-eléctrica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28895/18348))</sub>, magneto <sub>([máquina magneto-eléctrica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28895/18348))</sub>
  - disco <sub>(discoteca)</sub>, polio <sub>(poliomielitis)</sub>, quimio <sub>(quimioterapia)</sub>, sado <sub>(sadomasoquista)</sub>, seño <sub>(señorita)</sub>
- **Implicit feminine noun:**

  - **Letters:** [la letra] o, ro
  - **Times:** [las horas] cuatro, cinco, ocho
  - **Misc:** [la policía] [Gestapo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28893/18348), sinhueso <sub>(["la lengua"](https://archive.org/stream/lalenguadecervan01ceja/lalenguadecervan01ceja_djvu.txt))</sub>

---

<sup>1. Note however that [some](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=YCD8S5n6nD6NMUUtBY) abbreviations of feminine words are masculine e.g. *[el porno](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ThXjiN7), [el cromo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BL2nfP8)*</sup>

Comment: Some professions are still said with -o in common gender in some regions (yet falling out of use quickly). Examples: la abogado, la médico, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Colloquial shortenings: Results of shortening or abbreviation of compound words. Some maintain the gender with etymological awareness:

   > la moto ‘motocicleta’
   >
   > la foto ‘fotografía’
   >
   > la eco ‘ecografía’ (not included in the DLE).

   But in others the etymological feeling is not preserved: *radio, dinamo, magneto, polio ‘poliomielitis’.*

   People with little culture can consider, by analogy, these words as masculine and create a vulgarity with prosthetic a-. A phrase of the type "una moto", "alguna moto" they segment it as "*un amoto", "*algún amoto" and, from them, they create: *el amoto, *el afoto, *el arradio...
2. Common gender nouns referring to women: *la testigo, la soprano, la miembro*...
3. Learned nouns: The female latinisms in -o have always been subjected to the analogical force of the masculine ones in -o:  *la eco, la método* or *la cartílago* ended as masculine nouns: *el eco, el método* and *el cartílago*

   > “Al vislumbrar de la modesta luna le responde la eco solitaria.” (L. Fernández de Moratín, Poesías completas, 1778-1822).

   > “...lo cual se hará escriviendo con la método i términos devidos a cada cosa”. (Juan de Robles, El culto sevillano, 1631).

   Other learned nouns, as *caligo, virago* or *libido*, resist as feminine, although the first is not included in the DLE, the second fluctuates in gender due to its own meaning of sexual ambiguity and the third generates, as [we saw](http://www.blogolengua.com/2009/05/libido-livido.html), numerous errors:

   > “Lo oculto de Dios, según el lenguaje del libro del Éxodo, está representado en aquella nube densa y oscura, es decir, en la caligo”. “El ocultamiento luminoso de Dios...” José M. Moraga Esquivel).

   > “La caligo beltrao es una mariposa de las selvas brasileñas, que alcanza los 18 centímetros de envergadura alar.” (Animalandia, acceso 21-10-2009)

   > "La haitiana era una mulata auténtica; un virago color chocolate". (La Venus mecánica, José Díaz Fernández, 1929).

   > "Cuando el germano de estos siglos se ocupa en idealizar la mujer, imagina la walkiria, la hembra beligerante, virago musculosa que posee actitudes y destrezas de varón". (Artículos, Ortega y Gasset, 1917-33)

---

**Note:** the above is an abridged translation of [this blog entry.](http://www.blogolengua.com/2009/10/sustantivos-femeninos-terminados-en-o.html)

Comment: In the quoted text, _virago_ is used as masculine (the article in suggests so). The word is generally feminine, but it also admits being used as masculine

Answer (score 0):

Además, están:

[**libido**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NEw80OX)

> Del lat. *libīdo.*
>
> 1. **f**. Psicol. Deseo sexual, considerado por algunos autores como impulso y raíz de las más varias manifestaciones de la actividad psíquica.

y  [**ratio**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VEJNvfy)

> Del lat. *ratio.*
>
> 1. **f.** Mat. razón (‖ cociente de dos números). U. t. c. m.